# Any undersandable description of glTexEnvi (OpenGL ES 1.x)?

Tags: iphone, opengl, blending, multitexturing

I've seen as many different parameters as many source codes I saw. Is there a description can be found somewhere that **refers all about those parameters in details**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty comprehensive.

http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glTexEnv.xml

There are also some tex-env extensions -- I think at least add and combine are supported on most GLES 1.1 hardware, and I think PowerVR cores support dot3.

http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_env_combine.txt

http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_env_dot3.txt

http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_env_add.txt

The PowerVR SGX hardware has some fine print about combine modes - be sure to read the PowerVR docs.